# Cygwin git shows already committed changes

Tags: git, version-control, cygwin

I'm using git wit cygwin and I'm also using git via NetBeans. The problem I am having is when I commit changed files with NetBeans, when I run `git status` in cygwin, git still shows me the already committed changes. Somehow the git version on cygwin gets out of sync. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: what happens if you run a commit in cygwin now?

Comment: After running `git add -A` and `git reset`, `git status` is showing the correct status again. Is there a simpler way to get `git status` working right away?

Comment: the changes you commited in netbeans are now commited? not reseted?

Comment: Work flow was: Commit in NetBeans, did some more file changes. Then opened Cygwin. `git status` stilled showed the already commited files as changed. after `git add -A` and `git reset` cygwin showed the correct status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with phpstorm and git bash. My problem was that phpstorm automatically added new files to git, but in git bash they where not added.

In your case: when you create new files with netbeans, it automatically adds them to git, but cygwin doesn't. This is the reason why you have different states in cygwin and netbeans.

It would be much easier to use only netbeans OR cygwin for git commands. Other way you have to do a `git add -A` in cygwin, so that your new files are added to git.